# Is it possible to have extra tables in a Slave with MySQL Replication

Tags: mysql, replication

As my title mention I have a Master and a Slave database.

Master if for operations data and my slave mainly for reporting stuff.

The issue is that I need to create extra tables on reporting that can't be on the master, but the way my replication is set (the simplest one mentioned by the official doc)  at the moment, this breaks the replication system.

How could I add tables on the Slave without Master caring about it ? Is it even possible ?

Comment: It is totally possible and should work without a problem on the slave in a simple/common/default configuration, so please explain what you mean by "this breaks the replication system." Do you mean theoretically?  Or in your actual system?  In what way does it break?

Comment: @Spredzy Are you not interested in this question? Can you answer Michael's question?

Comment: Sorry I totally forgot about this thread back in the day, since I - at a later point - got the answer. When I initially though that creating table on slave was the issue, after debugging it further it revealed to be wrong, another action was acutally causing it. Creating the table on slave was fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got a rough idea how you setup replication. I think you have taken mysqldump --all-databases ... something along those lines.

Now if you want extra tables inside one of those database that you exported by mysqldump and those that belong to the master replication will break as you mentioned aswell.

Now to create more tables you need to create a new database with some name and then create tables in there. This will not break the replication.

I do not know if this helps....

Masood